# Reading a matrix from file in C doesn't work as expected

Tags: c, matrix

I would like to read a file like the following into a one-dimensional array which has already been allocated:

```
   4 4
   1 2 3 4
   5 6 7 8
   9 10 11 12
   13 14 15 16
```

The first line specified the number of rows/columns and is followed by the matrix values. My code is:

```
int rows, cols;
infile = fopen("input1.dat", "r");
fscanf(infile, "%d %d\n", &rows, &cols);
printf("Rows: %d, Cols: %d\n", rows, cols);
int i, j;
double cur = 0;
for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        cur = fscanf(infile, "%lf", &cur);
        printf("%lf\n", cur);
        matrix[(i*m)+j] = cur;
    }
}
```

Now the output is:

```
Rows: 4, Cols: 4
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
```

I've been searching the site for an hour now but I just can't figure out why none of the values is read, not even from the first line after the row/cols line. Thanks for any help!

Comment: What are `m` and `n`?

Comment: this is a standard scientific file format: first line give m and n 
then each line is a row.

Comment: You have `rows`/`cols` and `m`/`n`.

Comment: What he's saying is that you read those numbers into variables named "rows" and "cols" that you don't use, then use variables m and n for the loops. I'm surprised this compiles, since m and n aren't declared anywhwere (obviously there's code you're not showing us).

Comment: Sorry I left out that this is code from void read_matrix(double* matrix, FILE* infile, int m, int n)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 cur = fscanf(infile, "%lf", &cur);
```

This is the problem you are overwriting the value read

correct will be

```
 int read = fscanf(infile, "%lf", &cur);
```

Comment: What a stupid mistake. Thank you so much, it is working now! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
cur = fscanf(infile, "%lf", &cur);
```

You can't both read into `cur` and store the return value of `fscanf` into `cur` as well. Use a separate (`int`) variable to store the return value (and check that, `fscanf` can fail).

Answer (score 0):

`fscanf` returns 1 on success, so:

```
cur = fscanf(infile, "%lf", &cur);
```

does make `cur == 1`. Instead just try:

```
fscanf(infile, "%lf", &cur);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on the line

```
cur = fscanf(infile, "%lf", &cur);
```

You, first put the correct value at cur using fscanf,
but then you assign at cur the value that is being returned by fscanf
which is the number of items of the argument list successfully filled which is 1 in this case